# Harddrive speeds super slow despite SMART results in Linux Mint & Windows

Tags: linux, windows-10, linux-mint, hardware-failure, smart

Recently, I've decided to start using Linux Mint again, not long after installing it, I noticed severe degradation in harddrive performance. It's my secondary drive in my computer that is having the performance issues. (Windows on the main drive, and linux on the secondary one.) It would take nearly 5 minutes for the desktop to fully start responding and working correctly. I decided to take a look at the SMART data for the hard drive to determine if the drive is failing but it seems to be passing. I even ran an extensive self-test and it appears to work perfectly.

I decided to switch back to windows thinking it was a linux related issue, but to my surprise, the drive was performing just as bad. The disk was reported as being 100% used but only transferring about 300 kb/s.

The drive was working perfectly fine BEFORE installing Linux.

I've got no clue what to do at this point. Any help would be much appreciated.

NOTE: This is a Seagate drive, so the "Raw_Read_Error_Rate" is incorrect.

**/etc/fstab**

```
UUID=24a69257-d0a2-43e7-a2be-3d899f117887 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=A642-ED47  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
#/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
LABEL=Secondary /mnt/Secondary ntfs nosuid,big_writes,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,uid=1000,gid=1000,x-gvfs-name=Secondary 0 0
```

**Speeds using hdparm -Tt /dev/sdb:**

```
Timing cached reads:   23658 MB in  1.99 seconds = 11870.13 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads:  36 MB in  5.38 seconds =   6.69 MB/sec
```

**hdparm -v /dev/sdb**

```
 /dev/sdb:
 multcount     = 16 (on)
 IO_support    =  1 (32-bit)
 readonly      =  0 (off)
 readahead     = 256 (on)
 geometry      = 243201/255/63, sectors = 3907029168, start = 0
```

**Drive SMART details using smartctl in terminal:**

```
    smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-48-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST2000LX001-1RG174
Serial Number:    WDZDVDMQ
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0b9a920f6
Firmware Version: SDM1
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Apr 26 16:29:17 2019 MDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x79) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 330) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   081   064   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       124030894
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   091   091   020    Old_age   Always       -       9732
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   078   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       59080102
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   093   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       6587 (39 164 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       143
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   063   055   040    Old_age   Always       -       37 (Min/Max 28/38)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       33
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       13264
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   037   045   000    Old_age   Always       -       37 (0 15 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       4832 (117 32 0)
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       15136779555
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       15510203186
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      6466         -
# 2  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%      6458         -
# 3  Conveyance offline  Completed without error       00%      6456         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6455         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6455         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6454         -
# 7  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%      6454         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         8         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Output from **fdisk -l /dev/sdb**:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A07FCB2E-A138-4E65-90F2-61E4B8738E35

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1          34     262177     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb2      264192 3319967743 3319703552   1.6T Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb3  3319967744 3321016319    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb4  3321016320 3907028991  586012672 279.4G Linux filesystem

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

I recently wrote zeros to the drive, formatted it, re-partitioned it and even aligned the partitions with the sectors on the drive. It's still extremely slow. I'm getting speeds of 10 MB/s now instead of its rated 150 Mb/s.

The only thing I can say, is I ran Steam and installed a handful of games and then it started this whole thing again. It even continues to happen even after reboots. It seems to go away after waiting like 15-30 minutes ...

Someone, anyone ... please help. It's made boot times 8+ minutes and I can't open anything. I can no longer use my computer ...

Comment: If you disconnect the second HDD (with the power off, of course), does the primary one work properly again?

Comment: @AndrewMorton The main hard drive was never the issue, I should have specified. The Secondary drive is the issue.

Comment: In that case, can you disconnect and reconnect both ends of the second HDD's data cable, just in case there is a poor connection there? Also, do you have another computer you can try the slow drive in?

Comment: @AndrewMorton The drives are inside of a laptop. The only one I can disconnect and re-connect is the secondary one. The other one is a m.2 drive plugged into the motherboard directly. And I do have a second computer to try the drive in. I could see if the drive behaves normally in the other computer.
EDIT: Could a loose connection be the issue? Wouldn't something show up in the SMART details or not exactly? I don't entirely understand the SMART data.

Comment: The SMART data is just what the drive sees inside itself. I would expect a poor connection to cause data corruption, but I do not know if there is some sort of error detection which mitigates that.

Comment: @AndrewMorton So, the SMART data looks all good then? The drive is perfectly healthy?

Comment: The Reallocated_Sector_Ct is 0, so the drive has not had to reallocate any sectors. The Raw_Read_Error_Rate RAW VALUE has not exceeded 4294967296 ([explanation](https://www.ixsystems.com/community/threads/smart-raw_read_error_rate-on-wd-red.23391/post-150312)) so there is no problem there. It looks like the drive is healthy.

Comment: @AndrewMorton SO after a LONG time of experimenting ... I found that if I install Linux Mint and DON'T use Windows AT ALL it behaves fine. But the minute I boot windows to look at something, when I go back to mint ... Everything is super slow again.

Comment: Perhaps Windows tries to "repair" the disk. Can you get `fsck` to run in Mint, probably on the next reboot, and see if it finds any errors? You will have to check if `sudo touch /forcefsck` applies to your version.

Comment: @AndrewMorton After some very rigerous testing ... I've ran fsck and even ran checkdisk and everything in Windows ... Everything seems perfectly fine. I for the life of me can't figure this out and have spent DAYS AND DAYS trying to figure it out... It's driving me absolutely nuts! I wish I could figure this out ... Nothing has shown an error. Fsck, chkdsk, SMART, and everything says it's fine ... I also added more information to my initial question.

Comment: It seems strange that the HDD performance would degrade after running Windows on the same computer. The suggestions I found after quickly looking into the abysmal "Timing buffered disk reads" are that it could (still) be a poor connection: [Problems with buffered disk read performance](https://superuser.com/q/606475/272824) or perhaps the alignment is incorrect: [Poor SSD Performance, Low Buffered Disk Reads](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=180937).

Comment: I found this regarding alignment on a 4K-sector drive: [How to format a 4k sector hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337693/how-to-format-a-4k-sector-hard-drive)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I thought I had fixed the problem, but, BEHOLD. We're back at square one and it's performing just as bad, if not worse. It happened right as steam decided to try and install a few games. Everything else worked fine, but steam seemed to make the entire drive slow to a crawl. I'm getting speeds of not even 10 MB/s anymore.

Comment: Does [`iotop`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/469187/1115360) show anything to suggest why the disk performace is poor?